# numpy and pandas datetime handling in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to fit the curve to a time series as it explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639070/12012445

If I *do not* import pandas module - everything works like a charm.
If I do, and I have to, - I get "'datetime.timezone' object has no attribute '_utcoffset'"

it seems to me that the issue is with plotting step were it returns the coefficients for a polynomial p(x) which in turn depends on datetime...

I've gone through a number of hints, including [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64/13703721#13703721)

I'm quite desperate (5th-hour researching)

```py
import pandas as pd #note that I'm not even calling it anywhere... so confused

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import time


dates = [dt.datetime(1978, 7, 7),
     dt.datetime(1980, 9, 26),
     dt.datetime(1983, 8, 1),
     dt.datetime(1985, 8, 8)]

y = [0.00134328779552718,
     0.00155187668863844,
     0.0039431374327427,
     0.00780037563783297]


yerr = [0.0000137547160254577,
        0.0000225670232594083,
        0.000105623642510075,
        0.00011343121508]

x = mdates.date2num(dates)

z4 = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
p4 = np.poly1d(z4)

fig, cx = plt.subplots()

xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
dd = mdates.num2date(xx)

cx.plot(dd, p4(xx), '-g')
cx.plot(dates, y, '+', color='b', label='blub')
cx.errorbar(dates, y,
             yerr,
             marker='.',
             color='k',
             ecolor='b',
             markerfacecolor='b',
             label="series 1",
             capsize=0,
             linestyle='')

cx.grid()
cx.set_ylim(0, 0.03)
plt.show()
```

expecting:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the version of pandas and matplotlib you are using?

Comment: I dont understand your question. The code works fine without pandas library.

Comment: @Madhuri Sangaraju pandas 0.24.2, numpy 1.15.4, matplotlib 3.0.3

Comment: @Hue, that's right - the code works fine w/o pandas, but i have to have pandas in other areas.. i'm going to try [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769554/12012445) answer below, will let you know

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769554/12012445) below worked! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you import pandas, it would register its datetime converters to be used by matplotlib. Apparently there is a problem with those somewhere. And in case that happens, you may deregister them via

```
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.deregister_matplotlib_converters()
```

This will ensure matplotlib converters are used and those seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above works. On the other hand, if you want to keep use the pandas converter. However, the format of `mdates` is different. It counts number of days from year 0. Therefore, one can try to convert the  `mdates` format into the standard `datetime` format by the following:

```py
dd = mdates.num2date(xx)
t0 = mdates.date2num(pd.to_datetime(0)) # obtain 1970-01-01 in mdates
new_dates = pd.to_datetime(((dd-t0)*24*3600).astype(int), unit='s')
# explicitly register pandas converter to avoid a future warning
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
```

Note that the problem appears to be gone by pandas version 0.25.1